# Why *ptraced* dup2 works different than directly called dup2?

Tags: ptrace

I'm trying to redirect a tracee's stdout to a file.

For this I've:

1. attached to tracee
2. mmap'd some memory
3. copied the filename to tracee's memory
4. asked tracee to open the file

To reach these results I had to dig myself into [this](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) repository.

So far my results look good, I'm ptracing into a `top` command, and `lsof` can detect my effort (see last line):

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
top     421762 root  cwd    DIR  179,2     4096      17528 /root
top     421762 root  rtd    DIR  179,2     4096          2 /
top     421762 root  txt    REG  179,2   124856      12493 /usr/bin/top
top     421762 root    0u   CHR  136,1      0t0          4 /dev/pts/1
top     421762 root    1u   CHR  136,1      0t0          4 /dev/pts/1
top     421762 root    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0          5 /dev/null
top     421762 root    3u   CHR  136,1      0t0          4 /dev/pts/1
top     421762 root    4r   REG   0,17        0 4026533347 /proc/stat
top     421762 root    5r   REG   0,17        0 4026533348 /proc/uptime
top     421762 root    6r   REG   0,17        0 4026533346 /proc/meminfo
top     421762 root    7r   REG   0,17        0 4026533345 /proc/loadavg
top     421762 root    8u  FIFO   0,28      0t0        827 /tmp/mystdout
```

And this is my command's output (just for completeness):

```
[+] Allocated scratch page: 7fbd357000
[+] Opened the new fd in the child: 8 (/tmp/mystdout)
[+] Saved fd 1 to -1 in the child
[+] Duplicated fd 8 to 1
[+] Freed scratch page: 7fbd357000
```

What I'm trying to do now is the final step, which is to `dup2` the stdout of the tracee to the opened *file_fd* (8).

### Feasibility

I wrote a very small program to test how `dup2` works on the target platform (aarch64):

```
int i = 0;
while(1) {
    printf("helloworld %d\n", i++);
    sleep(1);
    
    if (i==5) {
        printf("Opening tmp file\n");
        int file_fd = open("/tmp/mystdout", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666, 0, 0);
        printf("File opened=%d\n", file_fd);
        
        int err = dup2(file_fd, 1);
        printf("dup2 result=%d\n", err);
        
        close(file_fd);
    }
}
```

This test program verified that I can close the *file_fd* after the *dup2* call and still the program will continue logging to this file by default.
Even my "dup2 result=1" is printed into the file (and not onto *stdout*).

Considering *dup2*'s return value of 1 matches with its expected behavior by its documentation:

> On success, these system calls return the new file descriptor.

### Trying to dup2 with ptrace

After verified *dup2* is working if called directly, I'm calling `dup2` now with ptrace in the tracee with arguments of `file_fd` (8) and `orig_fd` (1):

```
int err = do_syscall(child, dup2, file_fd, orig_fd, 0, 0, 0, 0);
debug("Duplicated fd %d to %d, return=%d", file_fd, orig_fd, err);
```

With this, the program's output changes to this:

```
[+] Allocated scratch page: 7fbd357000
[+] Opened the new fd in the child: 8 (/tmp/mystdout)
[+] Saved fd 1 to -1 in the child
[+] Duplicated fd 8 to 1, return=8 !!!
[+] Freed scratch page: 7fbd357000
```

As you can see, dup2 is executed successfully (positive return value), **BUT** it returned with *8* instead of *1*.

Again, I'm calling ptraced dup2 with this method:

```
int err = do_syscall(child, dup2, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I don't know how could I detail this method here as it's a bit too large, but for reference here is how I called *openat* which *actually* opened the desired file in tracee's process:

```
int file_fd = do_syscall(child, openat, AT_FDCWD, scratch_page, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666, 0, 0);
```

(Note: *scratch_page* is a memory mapped in tracee's space, and "/tmp/mystdout" is copied into it before using this instruction above)

So the question is:

**How can I debug the injected dup2? For example with *strace*?**

I wish to understand why it behaves *different* than when called directly from the small test application.

Comment: Confused. Your code says to have the child `dup2` then `close`, and you're wondering why it will `close` after the `dup2`?

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text. Cut/paste the text itself. In `lsof` output we can see that you have successfully opened `/tmp/mystdout`, but have _not_ successfully `dup2` it. So you should look at the return from `dup2` and see why it is failing.

Comment: "have *not* successfully dup2 it": How shall *lsof* look like when dup2 succeeds? I'm checking the return code of dup2, and when it is less than 0, there is an error report. But it seems succeeding from this point of view.

Comment: "How shall `lsof` look" -- write a trivial program to show that. Both `1` and `8` should resolve to `/tmp/mystdout`. Also, this output seems suspicious: `Duplicated fd 8 to 1, return=8` -- `dup2` is supposed to return the `newfd` (i.e. `1`) here.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that on `aarch64` for some reason, `dup2` is not able to injected.

No matter what I've tried, it always returned with weird results.

However after I changed `dup2` to `dup3` everything magically started working.

I'm still wondering on why `dup2` syscall can't work, but for now after days of digging and learning I'm happy with this result.